# How to display the percentage of the top 5 clients of Total expenditure

Tags: data-visualization, tableau-api

I have a problem in creating a logic for calculating the % contribution of the top 5 clients in the overall expenditure in tableau.
I have a data like this.

First column has data for client names and second column with the expenditure.
I want to see what percentage of the expenditure are top 5 clients contributing towards the overall expenditure.

I am thinking of using it using calculated field. Is there a solution to this?

-

Answer (score 0):

For the following I assume you want the 
Try the following:

1. Create a calculated field with the following formula: `{fixed [Client] : sum([Sales])}` and call it `[Total expenditure]`. That will calculate the toal expenditure per client
2. Create a Set with the following settings (choose `[Total expenditure]`instead of `[Total Sales]`):

[image]

3. Drop `[Total expenditure]` to Columns
4. Drop `[Set Top N]` to color
5. done
   [image]
6. If you want it more flexible you can create a Parameter `[Top N]` with these settings and choose this in the Set settings instead of your `[Total expenditure]` field: 
   [image]